# Firefox Issue table caption at 100% width goes outside parent element

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have an issue in Firefox where a table caption is not respecting the width of it's parent

for example I have

```
.table {
    width:50%;
    border: none;
    border-spacing:0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
 }

.table caption {
    Width:100%;
}

<table class="table" Style="float:left;">
<caption>Caption</caption>
</table>
```

However the caption will extend to 100% of the page width and not the parent. If I set it to a width of 50% it seems to respect the parent width. I have no issue on IE, Edge, or Chrome

Comment: Please post html markup

Comment: post has been edited to reflect markup

Answer (score 0):

First - make a more complete table to reflect real code

Second - don't set width to caption as there is no need for it

https://jsfiddle.net/uqfuvo5s/

```css
.table {
      width: 50%;
      border: none;
      border-spacing: 0;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
```

```html
<table class="table" Style="float:left;">
      <caption>Caption</caption>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```